# On android, how can I give only Beta Users access without using Google APIs

Tags: android, beta

What if you want to let Beta Testers test an app that will eventually be a paid app? And what if you don't want to use Google APIs, like checking against a Gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is NOT for releasing Beta through Google. It's for doing it on your own.

I'm beta testing a series of Chinese lesson apps right now and decided to use phone numbers to allow beta testers access. Note that you cannot always get a phone number from a phone device. But mostly you can.  Here's the class that does the checking:

```
package org.this_voice.ruzhechu01;

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class BetaPhoneCheck extends Object {

private String accessGranted = "false";
private Context appContext = null;
private static final Set<String> ACCESS_LIST = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList(
    new String[] {"2074583598"}));

public BetaPhoneCheck(Context context) {
    appContext = context;
}


public boolean hasAccess(){
    String thisNumber = getDevicePhoneNumber();
    thisNumber = thisNumber.replace("-", ""); //FIXME use fhandler's regex code
    return ACCESS_LIST.contains(thisNumber);
}


/*
 * not guaranteed to work...
 */
private String getDevicePhoneNumber() {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
        appContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}   

}
```

Here's a layout for access failure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="?textTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    style="?textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_access" />

<Button
    style="?button"
    android:id="@+id/accessExit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:onClick="exit" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here's for strings.xml:

```
<string name="no_access">BETA ACCESS FAILURE\n\nMake sure your phone is in service.\n\nEmail developer if you are unable to access your Beta App.\n\n</string>
```

And here's the onCreate code from the main activity:

```
    boolean hasAccess = new BetaPhoneCheck(this).hasAccess();

    if (! hasAccess){
        setContentView(R.layout.no_access);
    } else {
```

And the perm for the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Hope this saves people some time when they want to push apps out to beta. Enjoy.

Comment: Ι am not sure that this check complies with the Google Play Store rules and TOS!

Comment: Unfortunately getLine1Number doesn't always work.  It only works on some carriers.  And @Pavlos-  Google Play isn't the only app store.  FOr that matter most of my betas don't run through any app store, I hand them out via email and sideload.

Answer (score 0):

I've required people to email me their UUID and put a check on UUID in the launching Activity.  That doesn't scale to a large number of users though.  If you want to do that, you'll want a webservice that will check the UUID vs a list of allowed ids in a database.

Comment: After looking into it, nothing on my phone is labeled UUID. You pull it programatically. So phone or wifi MAC address, unless one wants to do a lot of explaining to beta users with no technical inclination.